# How can I fix the loop to return the object passed to `with_object`?

Tags: ruby, break

This script continuously takes a user's input until they enter `exit`, at which point the loop breaks. But why does the loop return `nil` and not the object passed to `with_object`?

```
puts "enter lines, type exit to finish"

loop.with_object([]) do |_,a|
  i = gets.chomp
  i == 'exit' ? break : a << i
end
 #=> nil
```

According to the [official documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_object) `Enumerator#with_object` should return the object passed to it.

Comment: You could instead write `i == 'exit' ? (raise StopIteration) : a << i`. [Kernel#loop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) handles the exception by breaking out of the loop, which is the normal way of terminating `loop`. For that reason, I prefer this over what you have, but it's minor. For better readability, maybe write this on two lines: `raise StopIteration if i == exit; a << i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write `break a` to redefine the return value of `break` which by default is `nil`.

```
loop.with_object([]) do |_,a|
  i = gets.chomp
  i == 'exit' ? (break a) : a << i
end
 #=> whatever #a is
```

In a sense `break` overrides `with_object`'s return value, so you have to manually set it back again.

Comment: The same is applicable to `inject`/`reduce` and `next`.